# Python using super with grandchild inheriting parent and child

Tags: python, python-3.6, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

[using Python3.6]
I have a design where Grandchild inherits a Parent and Child (of Parent).

```
class Parent:
    def aux_func(self):
        return "[parent aux]"

    def main_func(self):
        print("[parent main]" + self.aux_func())


class Child(Parent):
    def aux_func(self):
        return "[child aux]"

    def main_func(self):
        print("[child main]" + self.aux_func())


class Grandchild(Child, Parent):
    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        g = Grandchild()
        g.main_func()
        super(Child, g).main_func()
        Parent.main_func(g)

Grandchild.do_something()
```

the result is -

```
[child main][child aux]
[parent main][child aux]
[parent main][child aux]
```

Calling a function from Parent causes the aux_func to resolve from the Child class. I tried to go through MRO process but can't explain functions being called from different classes. Could someone help me with

1. Why this is happening ?
2. What would be a workaround to achieve [parent main][parent aux] ?

Comment: You are passing in the wrong class to `super()`. Pass in the **current** class, `Grandchild`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Thanks for chiming in. Problem is `super(Grandchild, g).main_func()` gives me `[child main][child aux]`. I'm trying to get both parent functions called.

Comment: Well, `self` is still an instance of the `Grandchild()` class. `super()` does not alter what `self` is bound to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That'd explain it. Thanks! I'm trying to come up with a design that allows me to call all functions from Parent or Child but not both. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `super()` does. `super()` does not alter the type of the `self` reference. `super(..., self).method()` will still pass in that `self` reference to the method being called, so `self` is, in all three cases, the `Grandchild()` instance.

That means that in all cases, `self.aux_func()` follows the normal attribute resolution order, and for `Grandchild()` instances, `self.aux_func()` will always find `Child.aux_func` and call that.

Put differently, the only lookup that is altered, is the attribute you look up on the `super()` object itself. If you need more such alterations, you need to use `super()` *again*, *or* you need to give your `aux_func()` functions *different names per class*. One way to do that is to make the methods *class private*.

The latter can be done by naming your function with two underscores at the start (but not at the end). Such names are then *altered at compile time* to inject the class names in all places that it is referenced:

```
class Parent:
    def __aux_func(self):
        # class private to Parent
        return "[parent aux]"

    def main_func(self):
        # any reference to __aux_func *in this class* will use
        # the Parent class-private version
        print("[parent main]" + self.__aux_func())


class Child(Parent):
    def __aux_func(self):
        # class private to Child
        return "[child aux]"

    def main_func(self):
        # any reference to __aux_func *in this class* will use
        # the Child class-private version
        print("[child main]" + self.__aux_func())
```

See the [*Reserved classes of identifiers* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> `__*`
>   Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes.

and the [*Identifiers (Names)* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> **Private name mangling**: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`. This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used.

By using class private naming for `__aux_func`, any reference to it from methods defined on `Parent` will look up and find `_Parent__aux_func`, and any reference to the same name in `Child` will look up and find `_Child__aux_func`. The two names are distinct and thus don't clash:

```
>>> class Grandchild(Child, Parent):
...     @classmethod
...     def do_something(cls):
...         g = Grandchild()
...         g.main_func()
...         super(Child, g).main_func()
...         Parent.main_func(g)
...
>>> Grandchild.do_something()
[child main][child aux]
[parent main][parent aux]
[parent main][parent aux]
```

A different way to achieve this is to use distinct names, explicitly; say `parent_aux_func()` and `child_aux_func()`. Class private names are really only *intended* in APIs that are meant to be subclassed by third-party code without too many restrictions on what names the subclass can use.